# Getting download statistics from ArcGIS Hub

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-hub

I have configured a new GIS page within ArcGIS Hub.  It contains links to other GIS sites as well as to local road closure apps, river levels, and other local information.  It also contains links to download our GIS data broken down into categories.

Is there a way to find out how many times our GIS data has been downloaded per feature within a given time period (i.e. downloaded centerlines 47 times in 4th qtr 2020)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve it.

You have to Set up a google analytics key and configure it on your site.

I am sharing a few helpful links that you can refer to.

1. Configuring sites [Configure site settings](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/hub/sites/configure-site-settings.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_564FACD5005D4F0A9F3D0F42A0E038FD)
2. Community ESRI [Open Data Portal Statistics](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-hub-questions/open-data-portal-statistics/td-p/752107)

This is how it looks:-

[image: This is how it looks]